# How to align this url directions

Tags: tables, urls

I am trying something like a table, where I have an ID(identification) and the url. It looks like this:

```
ID     url

I16 \url{https://randr.nist.gov/enzyme/DataDetails.aspx?ID=72WUR/HES_1276&finalterm=5.1.3.15&data=enzyme}

I1  \url{https://randr.nist.gov/enzyme/DataDetails.aspx?ID=97STA/SUA_1365&finalterm=Reaction:\%20\%20D-glucose\%206-phosphate(aq)\%20=\%20D-fructose\%206-phosphate(aq)&data=enzyme}

I2  \url{https://randr.nist.gov/enzyme/DataDetails.aspx?ID=88LIM/RAI_1287&finalterm=D-glyceraldehyde\%203-phosphate(aq)\%20=\%20glycerone\%20phosphate(aq)&data=enzyme}
```

Is it possible to make ID, I16, I1,.. to be align? I have tried with a table but was impossible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using a `tabularx` environment, along with a version of the `X` column type that doesn't perform full justification, should do the job. Do be sure, though, to load the `url` package with the options `hyphens`, `spaces`, and `obeyspaces`.

[image]

```
% (parts of preamble copied from OP's earlier postings)
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{report}
\usepackage[headheight=18pt,a4paper, width=150mm,top=25mm, bottom=25mm, 
    bindingoffset=6mm,headsep=18pt]{geometry}
\usepackage[spanish,es-noquoting]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{tabularx,ragged2e,booktabs}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}X}
\usepackage[hyphens,spaces,obeyspaces]{url}
\usepackage[colorlinks,urlcolor=black]{hyperref} % optional

\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} lL @{}}
\toprule 
ID & URL 
\\ \midrule
I16 &
\url{https://randr.nist.gov/enzyme/DataDetails.aspx?ID=72WUR/HES_1276&finalterm=5.1.3.15&data=enzyme}
\\ \addlinespace
I1  &
\url{https://randr.nist.gov/enzyme/DataDetails.aspx?ID=97STA/SUA_1365&finalterm=Reaction:\%20\%20D-glucose\%206-phosphate(aq)\%20=\%20D-fructose\%206-phosphate(aq)&data=enzyme}
\\ \addlinespace
I2  &
\url{https://randr.nist.gov/enzyme/DataDetails.aspx?ID=88LIM/RAI_1287&finalterm=D-glyceraldehyde\%203-phosphate(aq)\%20=\%20glycerone\%20phosphate(aq)&data=enzyme}
\\ \bottomrule 
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

Comment: very cool! I will probably accept but please don't forget to upload ss later!

Comment: @HernanMiraola - Added a screenshot

Answer (score 5):

### Table

In my opinion, those links are way too long to show them in their full length unless you explicitly need them written out like that. I assume you are already using the `hyperref` package (due to the `\url`), so I suggest using the `\href` command instead, like the following example (note that you can always change the colours of the links, i left the default boxes in to make it clear that they are links). It makes the links compact, yet still contain the full URL (mousing over in PDF output will show it):

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\begin{tabular}{l l}
\toprule
ID & Link\\
\midrule
I16 & \href{https://randr.nist.gov/enzyme/DataDetails.aspx?ID=72WUR/HES_1276&finalterm=5.1.3.15&data=enzyme}{randr.nist.gov}\\
I1 & \href{https://randr.nist.gov/enzyme/DataDetails.aspx?ID=97STA/SUA_1365&finalterm=Reaction:\%20\%20D-glucose\%206-phosphate(aq)\%20=\%20D-fructose\%206-phosphate(aq)&data=enzyme}{randr.nist.gov}\\
I2 & \href{https://randr.nist.gov/enzyme/DataDetails.aspx?ID=88LIM/RAI_1287&finalterm=D-glyceraldehyde\%203-phosphate(aq)\%20=\%20glycerone\%20phosphate(aq)&data=enzyme}{randr.nist.gov}\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

### Line

In fact, I even suggest not using a table at all. The `\href` command makes it easy to create these links in a single line. This might suite your tastes better:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

(...) and the details of each ID can be found by clicking on them, bringing you to the randr.nist.gov site:
\href{https://randr.nist.gov/enzyme/DataDetails.aspx?ID=72WUR/HES_1276&finalterm=5.1.3.15&data=enzyme}{I16},
\href{https://randr.nist.gov/enzyme/DataDetails.aspx?ID=97STA/SUA_1365&finalterm=Reaction:\%20\%20D-glucose\%206-phosphate(aq)\%20=\%20D-fructose\%206-phosphate(aq)&data=enzyme}{I1}
and \href{https://randr.nist.gov/enzyme/DataDetails.aspx?ID=88LIM/RAI_1287&finalterm=D-glyceraldehyde\%203-phosphate(aq)\%20=\%20glycerone\%20phosphate(aq)&data=enzyme}{I2}.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: great, I think I will use both answers. Thanks..